# Not able to access website url using beautiful soup and python while web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Link that I am scraping : https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests, re, sys
from selenium import webdriver
import re

IndusInd_url = "https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html"

html = requests.get(IndusInd_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

print(soup)


for x in soup.select("#display-product-cards .text-primary"):
    print(x.get_text())
```

Using the above code I am trying to scrape the titles of the card, but unfortuantely I am getting this output

```
<html><body><p>This website is secured against online attacks. Your request was blocked due to suspicious behavior<br/>
<br/>
 Client IP : 124.123.170.109<br/>
<br/>
Incident Time : 2021-02-24 06:28:10 UTC <br/>
<br/>
 Incident ID : YDXx@m6g3nSFLvi5lGg4wgAAAf8<br/>
<br/>
If you feel it was a legitimate request, please contact the website owner for further investigation and remediation with a screenshot of this page.</p></body></html>
```

Is there any other alternative to follow to scrape the details.

Any help is highly appreciated ! ! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this.
FYI: Make sure you have the right driver (firefoxe or chrome or whatever with right version)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html'

# open the chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')

# pings the specified url
driver.get(url)

# sleep time to wait for t seconds to wait for page load
# replace 3 with any int value (int value in seconds)
time.sleep(3)

# gets the page source
pg = driver.page_source

# beautify with beautifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg)

# get the titles of the card
for x in soup.select("#display-product-cards .text-primary"):
    print(x.get_text())
```

Below is output image

[image]

Comment: @Bum Bum Bole, sometimes due to website server busy or internet issue, website might load a little late and driver might fail to get the page source. On a safer side, you can mention sleep time right after the driver.get(url). First import time and after driver.get(url), mention this line of code time.sleep(3) you can replace 3 with any int value in seconds. I will edit the above code and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved without `BeautifulSoup`.

I define the locator with xpath with the value:

```
//div[@id='display-product-cards']//a[@class='card-title text-primary' and text()!='']
```

And utilize method `.presence_of_all_elements_located`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.indusind.com/in/en/personal/cards/credit-card.html')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='display-product-cards']//a[@class='card-title text-primary' and text()!='']")))

for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

driver.quit()
```